# Readline node.js undefined Math.floor function error

Tags: node.js, readline

I want to build node js console asking tool.
Please help, I have an undefined error in the console. What is the problem?

```
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const ask = msg => new Promise(resolve => 
  rl.question(msg, response => resolve(response))
);


const simpleInterest = (min, max) => {
  const math = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

const main = async () => {
  const min = await ask("min numer: ");
  const max = await ask("max number: ");
  console.log(simpleInterest(+min, +max));
  rl.close();
};

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `simpleInterest` function is not returning anything. Try this:

```
const simpleInterest = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, magic happens

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you should consider upvoting it and marking it as accepted :)